# Существительное "врач" - от глагола "врать"?

Tags: словообразование

Слышал мнение, что слово "врач" произошло от глагола "врать".  Верно ли это?

Comment: Повтор вопроса. Вопрос уже был задан: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/2385/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну да, от "врать", только не в современном негативном смысле, а в первоначальном-говорить, заговаривать. По Фасмеру: ст.-слав. врачь , болг. врач "колдун", сербохорв. вра̑ч "прорицатель", словен. vráč "врач". Эти слова производят от врать и ворча́ть. В таком случае первонач. знач. "заклинатель, колдун"; http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-2192.htm

В старославянском было и такое  наименование врача - балий, которое родственно старому глаголу баять (говорить, рассказывать).
Значит, врач действительно врал (а в старом значении этого глагола врет и сейчас) - в смысле, говорил. И пусть говорит: несмотря на все новейшие лекарственные средства слово доктора остается для нас самым нужным лекарством!

Словарь Даля утверждает, что слова "врать" и "врач"("врачун") - синонимы (слова "врач//врачун" даны в статье о слове "врать" с пометкой сиб., вероятно, слово врач имеет северные или сибирские корни).

Историческая связь между этими словами бесспорна и выглядит, по-видимому, так. Людей, как говорунов, рассказчиков, которые лечили от сглаза, порчи и других болезней заговорами, постепенно стали называть словами вракунья, вракун, врачунья, врачун, врачея, врачка, врач. Аналогично происходило и изменение слов, обозначающих род деятельности таких людей. Его можно представить в такой последовательности: врачебнословие, врачебство, врачевство и, наконец, врачевание (уже лечение в современном смысле).

Так Врач - вьрачь оказывается производным с помощью суффикса -ч-(чь) от глагола врать (вьрати).Такое значение было известно еще в XIX веке, ср. у А. С. Пушкина в повести "Капитанская дочка": "Полно врать пустяки, т.е. "Хватит говорить ерунду".